# How to rank fields in df2 based on booleans in df1 and create a third dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Can't figure out how to rank only the values with a True boolean from another df.

Example: Choose only fields with True in df1 and then rank those fields(True) in df2, keep only top 2 ranked as True and change the others to False in df3.

```
df1
date         x     y      w      z 
2017-02-02  True  False  True   True
2017-02-03  False True   True   True


df2
date         x    y    w   z 
2017-02-02   1    2    3   4
2017-02-03   2    4    1   3



expectation:

df3 (logic)
date         x                                   y               ... 
2017-02-02  (df1 is True and ranked 1 in df2,  (df1 is False, so df3 is False)
            which means top 2 -> True in df3) 

2017-02-02  (df is False, so df3 is False)    (df1 is True, so rank the True 
                                              in df2, which means it's ranked 
                                              3rd, so False)

Final:

df3
date         x     y      w      z 
2017-02-02  True  False  True   False
2017-02-03  False False  True   True
```

Comment: Hard to follow your logic , can you explain how to get the expected output cell by cell ?

Comment: Hi, let me know if it's clear now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check with `numpy` `argsort`. the hard part here is sort first get the `cumsum` which not exceed the limit 2 , then sort back

```
df1[:]=np.array([np.logical_and(x[y-1].cumsum()<=2,x[y-1])[(y-1).argsort()] for x,y in zip(df1.values,df2.values)])
df1
Out[330]: 
                x      y      w      z
date                                  
2017-02-02   True  False   True  False
2017-02-03  False   True  False   True
```

Comment: Been trying to figure out using suggestion. But I keep getting: IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type